# How to disable Alt-A keyboard shortcut in Windows' Bash (WSL)?

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I SSH with WSL Bash to another machine where I use an app that needs to receive the "Alt-A" keyboard sequence.

However it doenst work, I get a chime sound when I press Alt-A.

However, pressing Alt-X (in emacs through SSH) works

How can I allow the Alt-A keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, you're right. Yes, only under the bash subsystem.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways at least:

a) Remove key binding for "alt + enter":

1. next to the window title click a small "down arrow" and select "settings"
2. choose "actions"
3. find "Toggle fullscreen" and edit entry
4. select "delete"
5. save changes

b) use different terminal